# Как преобразовать json в json строку node js?

Tags: node.js, json, puppeteer

Мне необходимо экспортировать cookies из puppeteer в базу mysql, page.cookies() возвращает json я хочу этот json в виде обычной строки сохранить в mysql в одну из ячеек (ровно в том же виде в котором он выводится в консоль). Как я могу преобразовать JSON в 'JSON' в node?
Большое спасибо!

Comment: `JSON` это по определению строка. `page.cookies()` возвращает массив объектов. Для превращения объектов в JSON есть функция `JSON.stringify` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Спасибо большое, как раз вот только что нашел решение.